# How do you fix the map "green arrow" bug?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've encountered a map bug in 1.6.4 SMP, which is similar to this one explained [in the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Map#Bugs):

> Currently, placing a map on a wall in SMP using an Item Frame possibly
> causes an issue with maps held by players in which the location marker
> for the players 'disappear' under explored regions of the map, and
> preventing unexplored regions from becoming 'explored', effectively
> making all maps on the server useless. Deleting all of the map.dat
> files in the world data folder, as well as the idcount.dat file
> resolves the issue, unless players have maps in their inventory.

The difference is that despite not showing my marker, it *does* explore new areas, contrary to what is written there.

Also, *"Deleting all of the map.dat files in the world data folder, as well as the idcount.dat file resolves the issue"* is kind of vague: it may solve the issue, but does it cause any problem? Or are these only cache-like files?

PS: [reported](https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC-33254)

Comment: I have encountered the same - losing the marker, but being able to explore - in 1.6.1, IIRC, so the wiki may be indeed outdated on this. By the way, please specify your game version, so that the question does not become confusing later on.

Comment: Deleting those files, I believe, deletes all map data, blanking the maps. I'd suggest testing it in a disposable world first, to confirm the side effects.

Comment: I think they have fixed this in 1.7. I have been playing the pre-releases and it seems to have gone. I had the same problem in 1.6 as well.

Comment: @Dinopet123 I'll have a look, thanks

Comment: Your link is broken

Answer (score 1):

It is because you use a locator map and not a regular map. Also, an item frame technically traps an entity and keeps it from despawning. The locator map shows entities only with an arrow. This is also why you could see it. I've had this problem too so don't feel bad.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having is that the green arrow is the map on the wall meaning you placed a locator map like the one you spawn with. This doesn’t however happen with regular maps. Regular maps can be crafted with 9 paper.

Comment: Hi Bratworst, this was a post from 2013, for minecraft 1.6.4 - It was patched in 1.7.2 (The update that changed the world) https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/1.7.2

Comment: 2013? Wow! I’ll leave it on here because it is a problem on mobile currently.